# Varios errores de sintaxis en mysql

Tags: mysql, sintaxis

Hola buenas tengo este codigo de mysql que me da un error ya que los errores anteriores los he conseguido solucionar pongo el codigo actualizado:

```
SOURCE /home/alumno/Desktop/mysql/vehiculos.sql;
SOURCE /home/alumno/Desktop/mysql/veterinario.sql;
USE vehiculos;
ALTER TABLE Automoviles ADD Tipo VARCHAR('utilitario' 'monovolumen' 'todoterreno' 'familiar') NOT NULL AFTER Consumo;
ALTER TABLE Automoviles MODIFY Emisiones DOUBLE(2,2);
SHOW CREATE TABLE Automoviles;
ALTER TABLE Propietarios CHANGE Fecha_de_nacimiento nacimiento DATETIME DEFAULT NULL;
SHOW CREATE TABLE Propietarios;
ALTER TABLE Automoviles DROP Imagen;
SHOW CREATE TABLE Automoviles;
RENAME TABLE Propietarios TO Clientes;
DROP DATABASE veterinario;
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS Mascotas;
CREATE DATABASE Mascotas;
USE Mascotas;
CREATE TABLE ANIMALES (
    nom_animal VARCHAR(20),
    tipo VARCHAR(30),
    raza VARCHAR(30),
    peso INT,
    color VARCHAR(15)
) ENGINE=innodb;
CREATE TABLE VACUNACIONES (
    nombre VARCHAR(20),
    fechaVacunacion DATE,
    descripcionVacuna VARCHAR(50)
) ENGINE=innodb;
ALTER TABLE ANIMALES ADD CONSTRAINT `pk_ANIMALES_nom_animal` PRIMARY KEY (nom_animal);
ALTER TABLE VACUNACIONES ADD CONSTRAINT `pk_VACUNACIONES_fechaVacunacion` PRIMARY KEY (fechaVacunacion);
ALTER TABLE VACUNACIONES ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_VACUNACIONES_nombre` FOREIGN KEY (nombre) REFERENCES ANIMALES (nom_animal);
ALTER TABLE VACUNACIONES DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_VACUNACIONES_nombre`;
SHOW CREATE TABLE VACUNACIONES;
ALTER TABLE ANIMALES DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE ANIMALES CHANGE nom_animal Nombre VARCHAR(20);
ALTER TABLE ANIMALES ADD CONSTRAINT pk_ANIMALES_Nombre PRIMARY KEY (Nombre);
SHOW CREATE TABLE ANIMALES;
ALTER TABLE VACUNACIONES ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_VACUNACIONES_nombre` FOREIGN KEY (nombre) REFERENCES ANIMALES (Nombre);
SHOW CREATE TABLE ANIMALES;
```

He hecho un avance y ahora el unico error que tengo y que no consigo soluccionar es el siguiente:
En la linea 4 al intentar definir que el campo "Tipo" solo se pueda añadir los siguientes indices 'utilitario' 'monovolumen' 'todoterreno' 'familiar'
La linea es la siguiente:

```
ALTER TABLE Automoviles ADD Tipo VARCHAR('utilitario' 'monovolumen' 'todoterreno' 'familiar') NOT NULL AFTER Consumo;
```

Y el error es este:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4 in file: '/home/alumno/Desktop/mysql/modificaciones.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''utilitario' 'monovolumen' 'todoterreno' 'familiar') NOT NULL AFTER Consumo' at line 1
```

Muchas gracias de antemano, si alguien me puede decir que esta mal se lo agradeceria mucho.

Comment: ¿Y las comas? Cuando son errores de sintaxis, no olvides revisar la documentación, en este caso de MySQL.

Comment: Si es que he porbado poniendo comas y igualmente me da el error. Al final he conseguido averiguar gracias a un amigo cual era el error ahora pongo la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Resulta que al final el fallo de la linea:

```
ALTER TABLE Automoviles ADD Tipo VARCHAR('utilitario' 'monovolumen' 'todoterreno' 'familiar') NOT NULL AFTER Consumo;
```

Venia no solo por las comas (Que ya habia intentado anteriormente a ponerlas y no funcionaba aun) entre cada indice sino que tambien por que no seria varchar sino enum por lo que la linea finalmente quedaria asi:

```
ALTER TABLE Automoviles ADD Tipo ENUM('utilitario', 'monovolumen', 'todoterreno', 'familiar') NOT NULL AFTER Consumo;
```